# Can you define custom enum types for plist files?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, plist

I have an enum I've defined that is used to set configuration information. let's call the enum objectTypes

It defines a variety of different types, and the enums define human-readable names for these types.

My partner wrote setup code that loops through an array of objects and sets these type values. He used integer values.

Here is a crude outline of what he did:

```
for (int index = 0; index < [configArray count]; index++)
{
  ConfigObject aConfigObject = [configArray objectAtIndex: index];
  if (index ==0;
    aConfigObject.type = 7;
  else if (index == 1)
    aConfigObject.type = 5;
  else if (index == 2)
    aConfigObject.type = 3;
}
```

(This is pseudo-code to illustrate what I'm talking about.)

I did not like that for a couple of reasons. First, it's hard to read. What the heck is type 7? Second, if I add new enum types later, or change the order of the enums, it breaks. (The user-visible list of types is displayed in numeric order.)

I changed the code to say:

```
    aConfigObject.type = blueType;
```

Better, but still rigid code.

I want to move this configuration info into a plist file and read it at startup. However, that gets me back to the original problem. If I put these values into plist, I don't know of a way to use custom enum types. I'm forced to put numeric values in my plist, which makes the code plist to read and maintain.

Apple uses custom enum types all over the place in their plists.

Is it possible to define new custom enum types and teach the built-in plist editor in recent versions of Xcode (currently using Xcode 4.5) to understand those enums? That would be a huge improvement. I've done a fair amount of searching, but haven't found any answers so far.

Comment: Can you clarify something? What factor determines the TYPE of a `aConfigObject` object? Currently, you are using its position within the array to determine it, but can you tell me what property of the `aConfigObject` would you *like* to be the factor that determines its type?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the the configs to a pList file structured like the following:

[image]

Read that dictionary on startup with something like the following:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPlistFileName" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *myPlist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSDictionary *configs = [myPlist objectForKey:@"types"];
```

Now `configs` would have your configuration. You can now set your types like so:

```
aConfigObject.type = [config objectForKey:kBlueType]; // Assuming you have set up your constants for it.
```

now as for this concern:

> Second, if I add new enum types later, or change the order of the enums, it breaks.

It seems to me that you are using the position of the object within the array to determine its type.
So to make your loop less rigid, you can do something like so:

```
for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < [config count]; index++) {
    ConfigObject *aConfigObject = [configArray objectAtIndex: index];
    aConfigObject.type = [config objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", index]];
}
```

Comment: You misunderstand what I am asking. I want a way to teach the built-in property list editor about new enumerated types, other than the built-in types. I want to be able to create a property list and declare an entry to be of a new custom enum type, so that when I open the plist file, it shows the values using constant names rather than integer values. I'm guessing that there is a way to get Xcode to read a config file at startup that defines the enum types the property list editor supports.